# Editable synced sort order

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

How could I implement Firestore so that users can sort items in an array and the sort order is synced? For example order items in a Todo list.

I can come up with 2 alternatives. But they don't feel like good ideas..

1. Insert an item at a specified index. But I'm not sure how to or if you can do that with Firestore?
2. Every time you add a new item or "move" an item map new sortKey-values to each item then update all items. I might be able to so this with .batch but it feels super inefficient?

There must be a better way!

Is it easier to so with firebase real-time db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I'd recommend is to have a `position` field in your document that you will set to a floating point value. Listen to the collection with the query ordered by position. Then:

1. When putting an item at the end, give it a position of `lastItem.position + 100`
2. When moving an item, set `position` to `(prev.position + next.position) / 2.0`
3. When moving an item to the head of the line, `firstItem.position / 2.0`

This way you can continuously reorder items without having to do batched writes. Let's take a look at an example:

```
A: 100                   C:  50                    C:  50
B: 200                   A: 100 -> move below B    B: 200
C: 300 -> move to top    B: 200                    A: 300
D: 400                   D: 400                    D: 400
```

Comment: This sounds super smart!! But I don't quite understand 2. In the example it would be (100+200)/2=150?

Comment: `prev` and `next` refer to the neighbors of the new position. So the second example takes `200 (B) + 400 (D) / 2 = 300`

Comment: Aha okey! Now I understand!

Comment: But how many times can I divide by 2 until the precision is to precise (to many decimals), i.e the result gets rounded?

Comment: Lots. If you're super concerned about it, make your position add `1000000` or something instead of `100`. Or, periodically "clean up" positions by actually doing a batch write and resetting them all to nice whole numbers.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation to OP. What if I wanted to move a document an arbitrary number of places up/down? e.g. move D up two places, without knowing what B's `position` was? Sorting the list and then find what object is two places above D seems inefficient.

Comment: You need to know the sibling positions for my proposed strategy to work. Why would you need to be able to move an item between two other items you don't know about?

Comment: this was a perfect solution, thanks!