# How to reorder items in queue without knowing the index of the items

Tags: algorithm, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database, with a collection called `queue`, and its documents are items in the queue. I need to keep them ordered (FIFO), but also need to be able to move them up an arbitrary amount in the queue if necessary. They can't be kept ordered in the database. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916139/362840) answer to a question helps me with this. However, this assumes you know which items are in what position. This is the solution given:

> Have a `position` field that has a floating point value in the documents. Query the collection ordered by position. Then:
>
> 1. When putting an item at the end, give it a position of `lastItem.position + 100`
> 2. When moving an item, set `position` to `(prev.position + next.position) / 2.0`, where prev and next are of the prev and next of the new position.
> 3. When moving an item to the head of the line, `firstItem.position / 2.0`
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> A: 100                   C:  50                    C:  50
> B: 200                   A: 100 -> move below B    B: 200
> C: 300 -> move to top    B: 200                    A: 300
> D: 400                   D: 400                    D: 400
> ```

How can I do a move like "Move D up two places" without knowing that B is in the place I want to move it to? I don't want to have to sort the whole collection in order to move it because that's inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the position of items relative to each other, you will need to know the indices of those items. If you have no a priori knowledge that allows you to know their indices, you'll need to load all items in the range where you're modifying. There aren't any API shortcuts that help here as far as I can tell.